# Proc Transpose With multiple ID values per Group

Tags: sas, transpose

In this first data-set each employee has one team lead and one supervisor. I can transpose that no problem.

```
data a;
input employee_id ReportsTo $ ReportsToType $12.;
cards;
100 Jane  Supervisor
100 Mark  Team_lead
101 Max   Supervisor
101 Marie Team_lead
102 Sarah Supervisor
102 Sam   Team_lead
;
run;

proc transpose data = a
                out = aTP(drop =  _:);
by employee_id;
id ReportsToType;
var ReportsTo;
run; 
/* Output */
/*employee_id   Supervisor  Team_lead */
/*100                 Jane       Mark */
/*101                  Max      Marie */
/*102                Sarah        Sam */
```

Now, what if an employee can have anywhere from 1 to 3 team leads?

```
data b;
input employee_id ReportsTo $ ReportsToType $12.;
cards;
100 Jane  Supervisor
100 Mark  Team_lead
100 Jamie Team_lead  
101 Max   Supervisor
101 Marie Team_lead
101 Satyendra Team_lead
101 Usha      Team_lead
102 Sarah Supervisor
102 Sam   Team_lead
;
run;

/* Desired Output */
/*employee_id   Supervisor  Team_lead1     Team_lead2  Team_lead3 */
/*100                 Jane        Mark          Jamie             */
/*101                  Max       Marie      Satyendra        Usha */
/*102                Sarah         Sam                            */
```

Using proc transpose gives an error telling me I can't have more than one identical ID variable in each group. Is there a procedure for transposing which does allow this?

```
ERROR: The ID value "Team_lead" occurs twice in the same BY group
```

Comment: How would you like the resulting data to appear?

Comment: @RobertPenridge See the comment at the end "Desired Output"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your input data so that rather than the word `Team_lead` repeating, it shows it incrementing... i.e. `Team_lead1`, `Team_lead2`, etc...

You can use by-group processing and the retain statement to achieve this:

```
proc sort data=b;
  by employee_id reportstotype;
run;

data want;
  set b;
  by employee_id reportstotype;
  retain cnt .;

  if first.reportstotype then do;
    cnt = 1;
  end;

  if upcase(reportsToType) eq 'TEAM_LEAD' then do;
    reportsToType = cats(reportsToType,cnt);
  end;

  cnt = cnt + 1;

run;
```

Then simply call `proc transpose` like you did beforehand:

```
proc transpose data=want out=trans;
  by employee_id;
  id reportsToType;
  var reportsTo;
run;
```